# android remove a view from a dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-2.2-froyo, android-dialog

How would I remove a view from this dialog? I know I can remove a view from a <s>LinearLayout.removeView(id)</s>( LinearLayout.removeView(View) ), so if someone could tell me how to get (LinearLayout) R.layout.database_creation_form, that would be nice too. I am using Android-SDK V7

Java Code:

```
@Override
protected DialogInterface onCreateDialog(int id){
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
    final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.database_creation_form, null);
    setDialogViewAttributes(textEntryView);
    final EditText editText = (EditText)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.create_form_db_name_et2);
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.create_form_type_sp);
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(FileBase.this)
        .setTitle(R.string.create_database_string)
        .setView(textEntryView)
        .show();
}
```

XML for database_creation_form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingTop="25px">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/create_form_db_name_tv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/create_form_db_name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:paddingBottom="25px"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/create_form_db_name_et2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="text">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/create_form_type_tv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/create_form_type"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"        android:gravity="center"/>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/create_form_type_sp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post the xml for database_creation_form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
  final LinearLayout textEntryView = (LinearLayout) factory.inflate(R.layout.database_creation_form, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that database_creation_form contains somekind of linearlayout, lets assume its id = linearLayout.  Then the code below will allow you to get access to it.

```
LinearLayout mainLinear = (LinearLayout)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
```